# If $\langle f'(x) \cdot v , v \rangle > 0$ then $f$ is injective

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**

> Let $f: U \to \mathbb R^m$ differentiable at the convex set $U \subseteq \mathbb R^m$. If $$\langle f'(x) \cdot v , v \rangle > 0 , \,\,\, \forall\,\, x \in U, v \neq 0 \in \mathbb R^m $$
>   then $f$ is injective. If $f \in C^1$ then $f$ is a diffeomorphism of $U$ over a subset of $\mathbb R^m$. Give an example such that $U = \mathbb R^m$, but $f$ is not surjective.

**Attempt:** The idea is to show $$|f(x+v) - f(x)| > 0$$

As $U$ is convex and $f$ id differentiable in $U$ then $[x,x+v] \subseteq U$ for any $x, x + v \in U$, by the Mean Value Theorem there exists $\theta \in (0,1)$ such that $$f(x + v) - f(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x + \theta v) = f'(x + \theta v) \cdot v$$

Then $$\langle f(x + v) - f(x) , v\rangle  = \langle f'(x + \theta v) \cdot v , v\rangle > 0 $$

and I couldn't conclude anything.

The second part is **o.k.**

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** I  can't use the Mean Value Theorem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I figured it out.

Consider the function $$\begin{align}\psi: [0,1] &\to \mathbb R\\ t &\mapsto \langle f(a + tv), v \rangle\end{align}$$

defined at $[0,1]$, differentiable with

$$\begin{align}\psi' (t)  &= \langle f'(a + tv)\cdot v ,v\rangle + \langle f(a+tv),0 \rangle \\ &= \langle f'(a + tv)\cdot v,v \rangle > 0\end{align} \tag {*}$$

for $v = b -a$ and for all $t \in [0,1]$, then $\psi$ is strictly increasing at this closed interval. Now suppose that for $a \neq b$ we have $f(a) = f(b)$.

$$\begin{align}\psi (1) - \psi (0) &= \langle f(b), v \rangle - \langle f(a),v \rangle\\&= \langle f(b) - f(a), v \rangle\\ &= 0\end{align}$$

As $\psi$ is continuous and $\psi (1) = \psi (0)$ by Rolle's Theorem there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\psi ' (c) = 0$, which contradicts $(*)$ .Thus $f(a) \neq f(b)$ and it follows that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have already solved the problem. Pick $x, y\in U$, define your $v=y-x$, and proceed. Note that $||f(y)-f(x)||\cdot||y-x||>0$. As you picked $x\neq y$, then $f$ must be injective. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: I just found a counter example where I can't use the Mean Value Theorem for $f: U \to \mathbb R^m$, is there any way to walk around this?

Comment: Just for the record, this does not answer the question.

Comment: The point here is that, when you parametrize the segment $[x, y]\subset U$ you can use the M.V.T. for functions from $R$ into $R^m$.

Comment: Could you show me the proof somewhere, a paper or a reference?

Comment: You're right! I can't use MVT FOR path, instead i can use it for real valued function with several variables! The reference I use is Elon Lima's book, Curso de Análise, vol. 2!

Comment: I've been using the same book, what holds is the Mean Value Inequality. A counter example would be $f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb R^2$ defined as $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.

Comment: My answer seems to solve the problem. In case you are wondering, this is exercise 8.11 chap. V (pag 339) from this book.

Answer (score 0):

What about the second part? How did you prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism over $f(U)$?